# Coverage of a set in Euclidean space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, vector-spaces

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$. A coverage of $X$ is a family {$C_\lambda$}$_{\lambda \in L}$ of sets such that $X \subseteq \cup_{\lambda \in l}$ $C_{\lambda}$:

$(*)$ Subcoverage: If {$C_{\lambda}$}$_{\lambda \in l}$  is a coverage of $X$, a subfamily {$C_{\lambda}$}$_{\lambda \in l'}$, where $L' \subseteq L$  is a subcoverage of $X$ when $X \subseteq \cup_{\lambda \in l'}$ $C_{\lambda}$.

$(*)$ Open coverage: If {$C_{\lambda}$}$_{\lambda \in l}$ is a coverage of $X$, we say that it is open, if $C_{\lambda}$ is open for all $\lambda \in L$.

$(*)$ Elementary finite coverage: If {$C_{\lambda}$}$_{\lambda \in l}$ is a coverage of $X$, we say that it is finite if $L$ is finite. The coverage is said to be enumerable, if $L$ is enumerable.

$1.$ Show that if $X \subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$, then every open coverage of $X$, admits an enumerable subcoverage.

$2.$ If $K \subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$, then $K$ is compact if and only if every open coverage of $K$ admits a finite sub-coverage.

Could someone please guide me in solving these two exercises? I can't see the way

Comment: HINT: $X\subset \bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N} B(0,n)$.

Comment: @TitoEliatron If X is the union of all open balls in the way you indicate then by definition it has an open coverage, and then it admits an enumerable subcoverage since n is finite, like this?

Comment: look my edited comment.

Comment: @TitoEliatron I think I still don't see it clearly

Comment: I deleted the tag "covering-spaces" because this has nothing to do with your question. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space .

Comment: @PaulFrost you're right

Comment: What is your definition of compact?

Comment: @PaulFrost a closed and bounded set